# Django simle model implementation

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hi guys i have two classes one is Person and second one is Shirt.I was to assign shirt to specific user.For example person1 has 2 black shirt size L and 1 blue size 'XL' and person has 1 black shirt but size 'M' and 1 blue size 'XL'.

`class Person(models.Model):
    fist = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Shirt(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    quantity = model.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    size = model.CharField(max_length=3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Person might have many Shirts, you can add ForeignKey to Shirts.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    fist = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Shirt(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

Comment: thanks for quick response.I wasn't sure which relations should i use.